# Using TailwindCSS to put logo in top left and menu in top right

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have managed to write some Tailwind CSS to put a logo in the top left hand corner of the screen, but now I cant seem to get a menu to render in the top right, this is what I have. Nothing I try seems to work. It just renders right next to the logo image

```
<div className="isolate">
    <div className="px-6 pt-6 lg:px-8">
        <div>
            <nav
                className="flex h-9 items-center justify-between"
                aria-label="Global"
            >
                <div
                    className="flex lg:min-w-0 lg:flex-1"
                    aria-label="Global"
                >
                    <a href="/" className="-m-1.5 p-1.5">
                        <span className="sr-only">This Company Name</span>
                        <img
                            className="h-8"
                            src="/this-company-logo.png"
                            alt="This Company Name"
                        />
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove this tag:

```html
...
<div className="flex lg:min-w-0 lg:flex-1" aria-label="Global">
  ...
</div>
...
```